# Ionic when to save to local storage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm working on a pretty basic ionic app where I need to be able to save a simple array of objects for whenever the user relaunches the application. The problem I'm facing is that i don't really know where to save.

My question is: at what point of the code should I save the array on local storage? It seems silly to continuously keep saving the same array. Ideally it would only happen before the application is terminated, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But how would you decide when the app is closed? You might need some periodic mechanism to store that value. Can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$ionicPlatform.on('pause', callback)` and save your data inside the callback.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/